# Facebook page I have admin rights to displays "This content isn't available at the moment""

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My personal FB account is an admin of a FB page. When I view that FB page's public URL as my personal account, it displays the message

> This content isn't available at the moment

If I create a new FB account in a different browser, and visit the FB page's public URL again, the same message is displayed.

Help appreciated.